# Order data by child node's value - Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve all recipes favorited by a user using this code, but no data is retrived

```
recipesQuery = mDatabase.child("recipes").orderByChild("favoritedBy").equalTo(getId());
```

This is my Structure:

```
{
  "-KNnrgEmF8qCpsWiIMW4" : {
    "favoriteCount" : 4,
    "favoritedBy" : {
      "0ZtxMXZ8iDV4u0POxu8n6cIwCX33" : true
    },
    "name" : "Recipe 1",
    "recycleCount" : 0,
  },
  "-KNvq6Ts8RYxc0-O3B2t" : {
    "favoriteCount" : 2,
    "favoritedBy" : {
      "0ZtxMXZ8iDV4u0POxu8n6cIwCX33" : true
    },
    "name" : "Recipe 2",
    "recycleCount" : 0,
  }
}
```

If I remove the `.equalTo()` method all data is retrieved, but thats not what I want.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no method to filter a query based on other objects than String, Boolean, or Double.

What I suggest is to restructure your database to something like this

```
{
    "users": {
        "userId1" : {
            "name" : "User1",
            "favorites": {
                "-KNnrgEmF8qCpsWiIMW4" : true,
                "-KNvq6Ts8RYxc0-O3B2t" : true
            }
        },
        "userId2" : {
            "name" : "User2",
            "favorites": {
                "-KNvq6Ts8RYxc0-O3B2t" : true
            }
        }
    },
    "recipes": {
        "-KNnrgEmF8qCpsWiIMW4" : {
            "favoriteCount" : 4,
            "name" : "Recipe 1",
            "recycleCount" : 0,
        },
        "-KNvq6Ts8RYxc0-O3B2t" : {
            "favoriteCount" : 2,
            "name" : "Recipe 2",
            "recycleCount" : 0,
        }
    }
}
```

Then it's easier to get the recipes favorited by specific user.

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(userid).child("favorites")
```